# Issue running python scripts in docker container outside of run -it /bin/bash

Tags: python, docker, xvfb

So I have a weird issue with a python script I'm trying to run... this works:

```
docker run -it <my image> /bin/bash

<inside container> xvfb-run python myscript.py <arg>
```

Everything starts up, firefox launches in headless mode, it's all good.

This doesn't work:

```
docker run -d <my image> /bin/bash -c "xvfb-run python myscript.py <arg>"
```

docker top  shows that the cmd is running, but nothing else happens.

Why would the behavior be different from when I'm running it the second way?

Comment: What happens if you add `-t` or `-ti` to the second command?

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately. Docker top shows /bin/sh /usr/bin/xvfb-run python myscript.py <arg> and Xvfb :99. Looking at top when running it successfully, I see the exact same Xvfb information, so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else who runs into this problem, here's how I ended up solving it:

Don't use xvfb-run. I'm not sure why but docker gets really unhappy. You need to have Xvfb already running in the background. But you have to do it a certain way!

I wasn't able to get Docker working with Xvfb in a RUN command, but it was happy running out of a script. Create a script called start_headless_display.sh and have it look like this:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16 &
python /myscript.py <args>
```

In your Dockerfile, make sure the script will be part of your image and add these instructions:

```
ENV DISPLAY :1.0

RUN chmod a+x /start_headless_display.sh

CMD /start_headless_display.sh
```

Now when you run

```
docker run -d <your image>
```

Everything should work - docker top will show your script and Firefox chugging merrily away.